Why $-(-a)=a$ for $a\in\mathbb R$?
I know since long time that $-(-a)=a$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$. I'm a little embarrassed to say it, but I realize that I always accepted it but don't really understand why. I'm trying to explain it to someone that is a student in High School, but after thinking, I'm not so sure how to explain it. Can someone explain why we have such result ?

This should be reopened.  The replies to this question are university level responses while the question is asking for a response that a High School student can understand.  The context of the question is different and needs to be taken into account.

When I said "replies to this question" I meant replies to the duplicates.

For a High-School explanation : we have that $x-x=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Set $y=-a$ and $z=-y$. We have that $$a-z=a+y-y-z=a+\underbrace{y}{=-a}+\underbrace{(-y)}{=z}-z=a-a+z-z=0.$$ Therefore, $$a=z=-y=-(-a),$$ as whished.

Its because of the positioning of real numbers in the number line where $-a$ and $a$ are positioned in equal distances from $0$ and are in opposite directions from each other with reference to $0$.

I'm sorry your question was closed.  If you want to email me at the address in my profile, I'll be happy to send you a high-school level justification of the $--x=x$ identity.
